# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '@P0'

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I have an SQL server 2008 procedure which is returning one out parameter, i am giving call to it from java. My code is given below

Stored procedure code is

```
Create PROCEDURE countInfected @infected int out
AS
Select @infected = COUNT(*) from userInfo
where userID NOT IN (Select userID from deletedInfo);
```

Java Calling Code is

```
CallableStatement infected = null;
infected = con.prepareCall("call countInfected(?)");
infected.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
infected.execute();
System.out.println("Infected"+ infected.getInt(1));
```

but infected.execute(); is generating the following error

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '@P0'

kindly guide me where is problem

Comment: This any good to you:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mybatis-user/DxLHOn8LZU0/dFRgaIL7Ez8J  ?? Basically put braces around, like this "{ call countInfected(?) }"   (my SQL Server is toasted so I can't check).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As suggested by [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mybatis-user/DxLHOn8LZU0/dFRgaIL7Ez8J) offered up by @GregHNZ, SQL Server requires a set of curly braces around the call.

The line in your code would look like this:

```
infected = con.prepareCall("{ call countInfected(?) }");
```